# Finding multiple keywords and highlights the row

Tags: excel, vba

In Tab 1, I have multiple rows and columns(Say Column A to Column K with atleast 1000 rows). And in tab 2, I have listed the keywords(Column A with the keyworks A1-A50).

I'm trying to find a macro that searches tab 1 with any keyword that is in tab 2, and highlights the cell in tab 1 where it was found.

How do I write a macro for this ? I'm new to the macro world and excel..any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The best place to start is by recording a macro while doing it manually. It will write the code for you then.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer if you do not provide code or screenshots.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColourMatchingCells()

With Thism Tab2range as range
'Replace Sheet2 below with whatever Tab 2 is named -- and A1:A50 with actual range address.'
Set Tab2range = .worksheets("Sheet2).range("A1:A50")

Dim cell as range

' Again, replace Sheet1 name and range address on next line with actual values'
With .worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1:K1000")

Dim AddressOfFirstMatch as string
Dim CellFound as range
Dim MatchAddress as string

For each cell in Tab2range

' Case insensitive search and which tries to find the whole value. You did not mention what type of data you're searching for e.g. strings, numbers, dates, etc. -- or what type of search you want. '

Set CellFound = .cells.find(what:=cell.value2,lookin:=xlvalues,lookat:=xlwhole,searchdirection:=xlnext,Matchcase:=False)

If not (CellFound is nothing) then
AddressOfFirstMatch = CellFound.address
CellFound.interior.color = vbblue 'just an example'

Do
Set CellFound = .findnext(CellFound)
CellFound.interior.color = vbblue
MatchAddress = CellFound.address
Doevents ' If you experience infinite loop or bad logic, spam/hold Escape or Break key on keyboard'
Loop until strcomp(AddressOfFirstMatch,MatchAddress, vbbinarycompare) = 0

End if

Next cell

End with

End with

End Sub
```

Does it work? Does it do what you want?